# How can i call web service using HTML developed in Kendo UI?

Tags: mobile, kendo-ui

I am working on mobile application development using Kendo UI and would like to know if I can access web services using Kendo UI interface?

Answer (score 0):

YES! You can access web services with Kendo UI Mobile.

OK, ok... I'll give you the link...
http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/Mobile/Kendo%20Mobile%20Music%20Store/kendo-mobile-music-store-data

Comment: You can also download sample demo of above kendo Music Store Demo.
https://github.com/telerik/kendo-music-store